# Is there (free) software than decrypts a single file on Windows and Android?

Tags: encryption, windows, android

So, I have a document that I frequently access and update using VeraCrypt. I can access the document on multiple PCs by putting the VeraCrypt file in my Google Drive account. However, I can't access the document if I'm not at home at my computer, because there's no option for accessing the file on android (which is what my phone uses).

I know that there are apps that work on both Windows and Android, but none of them seem right for me.

- BoxCryptor takes access to my whole Google Drive account, which I don't like... I want something that just decrypts a single file stored locally
- EDS, 1) isn't free and 2) would require my phone to be rooted, which sounds like a lot of effort...

So I was hoping that someone could suggest a solution.

Comment: For Android, you can check [my list of apps for file/directory encryption](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_encrypt). Do a Ctrl-F for "Windows", and you'll find a couple of apps supporting both platforms. Not being a Windows user, I cannot say how well that works and didn't test any of those – but it should get you started at least ;)

Comment: @Izzy, none of the apps in that list have both Windows and Android listed as supported systems. Also, what happened to the nine comments on this post in which people debated which forum this post belongs in? Have they been deleted in an Orwellian attempt to rewrite history?

Comment: "none of the apps in that list have both Windows and Android listed as supported systems" – huh? All of them are Android apps, and 3 of them are listed to have Windows pendants (SSE, Panbox, Crypt4All). And yes, obsolete comments get deleted on SE sites (which are Q&A sites, not discussion boards/forums). In this special case, all 15 of them belonged to the original site (Security.SE) and were of no relevance here (SoftwareRecs.SE).

Comment: ok, my mistake. I didn't realize they were all android apps. I'll take a look. Thanks